# Programmatically set textblock margin

Tags: c#, wpf

I was wondering how you can set a textblock's margin programmatically? I have a list of strings, that I want to assign to each textblock and animate each one with a spacing in between each textblock. Just now, all the textblocks are on the same line, so I can't make out what the text says.

```
foreach (var i in item.Items)
{
    TextBlock tb = new TextBlock();
    tb.Height = 50;
    tb.Width = 900;
    tb.Text = i.Title + "\n";

    SlideDown(tb);
    canvas.Children.Add(tb);
}

public void SlideDown(FrameworkElement uc)
{
    ThicknessAnimation tAnimation = new ThicknessAnimation();
    tAnimation.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5.0));
    tAnimation.From = new Thickness(0,0,0,0);
    tAnimation.To = new Thickness(0, 500, 0, 500);
    Storyboard.SetTarget(tAnimation, uc);
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(tAnimation, new PropertyPath(FrameworkElement.MarginProperty));
    Storyboard storyboard = new Storyboard();
    storyboard.Children.Add(tAnimation);
    storyboard.Begin(uc);
}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can set the `Margin` property like this:

```
  double left = 1, top = 2, right = 3, bottom = 4;
  textBlock.Margin = new Thickness(left, top, right, bottom);
```

or you can specify a single value which applies to all above:

```
  double all = 5;
  textBlock.Margin = new Thickness(all);
```

Answer (score 3):

Refer to margin property [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.margin.aspx).

```
tb.Margin = new Thickness(10);
```

Comment: Actually no, it is correct, but I have to incrementally increase the margin after I add each textblock so the text is on different margins. Thanks anyway. :)